# Mahout movieLens recommender, where are the output files?

Tags: slf4j, mahout, mahout-recommender

I am running mahout Recommender located in the mahout wiki stater, following a successful build after the comand:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.example.grouplens.GroupLensRecommenderEvaluatorRunner" -Dexec.args="-i ratings.dat"
```

I see this log file and could not find any output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'exec'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Mahout Examples
[INFO]    task-segment: [exec:java]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing exec:java
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[WARNING] POM for 'asm:asm:pom:3.1:compile' is invalid.

Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[INFO] [exec:java {execution: default-cli}]
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 20 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 04 14:47:33 PST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/697M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Where are the logs/outputs? How can I enable logs?
Where are the recommendations? Am I doing some thing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That class you are running is described as ***"A simple example "runner" class which will evaluate the performance of the current implementation of GroupLensRecommender"***, which will only give you the ***"average absolute difference between predicted and actual ratings for users"***, also known as the ***"mean average error"***

So, you are not really generating recommendations.

Ted Dunning's github account has the Mahout In Action book examples ([link](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA/tree/master/src/main/java/mia)). You should have a look.